# jQuery .closest() not selecting nearest element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

For some reason I'm having trouble in selecting an element above another element. I would like to select the nearest `.discount-dropdown` class that sits aboove the `.discount-type` class. What am I doing wrong?

HTML (multiple of these):

```
<div class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle discount-dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">$ <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right adjustment-dropdown" role="menu">
        <li><a class="discount-type">$</a></li>
        <li><a class="discount-type">%</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.discount-type').on('click', function(event){
    $sign = $(this).html().substr(0,1);
    $parentElement = $(this).closest('.discount-dropdown').html(); //this isn't working
    $newHtml = $sign + $parentElement.substr(1);
    alert($newHtml);
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

because button is not a parent of `li`

```
$('.discount-type').on('click', function(event){
    $sign = $(this).html().substr(0,1);
    $parentElement = $(this).closest('ul').prev('.discount-dropdown').html(); //this isn't working
    $newHtml = $sign + $parentElement.substr(1);
    alert($newHtml);
});
```

I would suggest some changes in the way in which you are updating the currency like

```js
$('.discount-type').on('click', function(event) {
  var sign = $(this).html().substr(0, 1);
  $(this).closest('ul').prev('.discount-dropdown').find('.currency').text(sign)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input-group-btn">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle discount-dropdown" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false"><span class="currency">$</span> <span class="caret"></span></button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right adjustment-dropdown" role="menu">
    <li><a class="discount-type">$</a></li>
    <li><a class="discount-type">%</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Closest function will search for closest parent with given criteria, your button is not any parent of your element. So using closest can be used to find parent for both your elements - discount-type and your button. Having handler to your parent, you can find your button.

```
    $buttonElement = $(this).closest('.input-group-btn').find('.discount-dropdown').html();
```

- *input-group-btn* - is parent for both elements
- *discount-dropdown* is a child element for *input-group-btn*

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('.discount-type').on('click', function(event){
    $sign = $(this).html().substr(0,1);
    $parentElement = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('.discount-dropdown').html(); //this is working fine
    $newHtml = $sign + $parentElement.substr(1);
    alert($newHtml);
});
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/m6hnatjf/)

Answer (score 0):

use `closest('ul')` instead of `closest('.discount-dropdown')`.
You could also use `parentsUntil`+`parent`

```
$(this).parentsUntil('.discount-dropdown').parent().html();
```